# How to setup blacklist rule of elastalert

Tags: syslog, elasticsearch

I have syslog messages of following type. I want to capture all such messages which contains "errors" in message field of syslog.

```
<30>Apr  9 04:27:13 ip-172-31-26-235 POSTMETHOD_fx-control-plane.1.k61c5pc0vd89zlrr3uwt7cj82/c720d84be94a[24233]: 2019-04-09 04:27:13.276  WARN 6 --- [    container-2] ingErrorHandler$DefaultExceptionStrategy : Fatal message conversion error; message rejected; it will be dropped or routed to a dead letter exchange, if so configured: (Body:'[B@2ce66e13(byte[3009])' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=application/x-java-serialized-object, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=fx-exchange, receivedRoutingKey=fx-default-response-queue, deliveryTag=87, consumerTag=amq.ctag-wDCsD1_770goBmFKBAOhug, consumerQueue=fx-default-response
```

For achieving this result, i am using elastalert  blacklist rule with following configuration

```
es_host: elasticsearch

es_port: 9200




es_username: elastic
es_password: changeme



name: Slack blacklist rule


type: blacklist


index: logstash*



compare_key: message

blacklist:

- "error"

realert:
  hours: 1

filter:
  - query:
     query_string:
      query: "error"

alert:

 - slack
 slack_webhook_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/******/*****/*******"
 slack_username_override: "ElastAlert"
```

i not able to figure out what is wrong with configuration to achieve my desired result of capturing all messages of syslog with message field containing error.

Answer (score 0):

my idea was to capture all messages which contains error in message field of syslog. i used any type of rule of elastalert to get it. here is my config

```
    es_host: elasticsearch

    es_port: 9200




    es_username: elastic
    es_password: changeme



    name: Slack error rule


    type: any


    index: logstash*


    timeframe:
      hours: 4


    filter:
     - match:
        message: "error"



    alert:

    - slack
    slack_webhook_url: "https://hooks.slack.com/services/*******/*****/*****"
    slack_username_override: "ElastAlert"
```